# hide minitests results window in rubymine

Tags: rubymine

The minitests results window in rubymine is driving me crazy.  I get the results at the bottom but I don't want the huge window blocking the upper right portion of my screen.

I cannot figure out how to disable this notification window.

I realize I could just not auto-run the tests but I would like to have them run in the background without the constant notification.

Attaching a picture to demonstrate what window I am talking about

[image: minitest results]

I am using RubyMine version 7.1.2 on Ubuntu

I have tried disabling notification but this seems to not have any effect

[image]

Comment: Is this occurring when RubyMine has focus?

Comment: yes.  I can just add a space to a file and wait a second and it will pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable all system notifications like this in RubyMine by going to *Appearance & Behavior > Notifications* in the Preferences and Unchecking the **"Enable system notifications"** box. There is no more granular preference that I am aware of which still preserves the in-app balloon notifications as well.

Comment: this seems to have no effect on this window.

Comment: I suppose you should try double-checking the preference, applying it again, try restarting RubyMine, and from there open up an issue with JetBrains. What you're seeing is just the system notification on Ubuntu. That checkbox does affect the expected behavior on my OS X system.

Comment: ah I didn't realize this was a ubuntu notification

Comment: i have logged a bug with jetbrains but have partially worked around it by customizing the windows so it isn't so obnoxious.